# Postgres: Moving tuple count computation per hour, /w missing values

Tags: postgresql, time-series, sliding-window

I have a table "district_sensor_data":

```
+----------------------------+--------------+-------+
|         timestamp          | district_id  | value |
+----------------------------+--------------+-------+
| 2020-04-06 00:04:20.000000 |      4       |  14   |
| 2020-04-06 00:09:40.000000 |      8       |  15   |
| 2020-04-06 00:06:25.000000 |     11       |  15   |
| 2020-04-06 00:06:45.000000 |     11       |  16   |
| 2020-04-06 00:00:30.000000 |      1       |  36.4 |
| 2020-04-06 00:00:35.000000 |      1       |  39.4 |
+----------------------------+--------------+-------+
```

- The sampling rate is 5 seconds and there are multiple tuples with the same timestamp
- However, there are also missing timestamps.
- The data reaches over multiple days.

What is this about?

- I'm building an app to visualize my data
- There is a timeline component which allows you to select a 1-day window of data which is displayed.
- The selection of this time window is through scrolling, so there are a lot of possibilities "which out of all the possible 24-hour windows" is selected.
- I want to color-code the amount of values per district_id in the current 24-hour window. Thus, I need a minimum and maximum number of values for the scale.

Here is where the sliding window comes into play.

- I want to get the count of values for, in theory, every possible 24-hour window, grouped by district_id.
- Since this might take too long, I was thinking of not doing this for every single one of the tuples. So first, I could group into 1-hour bins (also per district_id) and then apply the sliding window. But I could happily skip this simplification.

I already looked into Postgres window functions, but I can't even get close to what I'm aiming for.

My main problem is the non-continuous time series, which makes it impossible to specify the window size using a row count. Is there a way to define the window temporally, as a 24-hour window?

Then, I don't know how I would incorporate a "ground truth" time series using `generate_series()` to allow for one computation every 5 seconds.

Pretty much the only thing which I managed to execute without errors, but not even close for my goal:

```
SELECT extract(HOURS FROM dsd.timestamp) as hour,
       sensor_id,
       value,
       count(value) OVER (

           PARTITION BY district_id, sensor_id
           ORDER BY timestamp
           )

FROM district_sensor_data dsd;
```

edit: I changed the post for some clarifications and removed the sensor_id, since it's actually not relevant here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you add the expected output for your sample data?  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the sliding window.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, my post was indeed a bit vague. I tried to give some more information about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure I understand.  Some expected results would still help.  Are you looking for the count along with the values (where there are any values)?  Should the count be over the previous 24 hours or the following 24 hours or 12 hours on each side?